# ImageView width = 0.75x screen width & height = 1.5 x new ImageView width XML

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview, android-glide

I'm loading the images into an ImageView using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Before the images are loaded from internet, I'm adding a **placeholder image until the image finishes loading.**

The images that I'm loading fortunately have a fixed aspect ratio, i.e. height/width = 1.5

I have the following requirements:
The width of the image view should occupy 75% of the screen width.
The height should be precisely 1.5 times the **NEW screen width**,
i.e.

```
width = 0.75 * screenWidth; 
height = 1.5 * width;
```

Curretly I'm achieving this **programatically** this way

```
mImageViewPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
mImageViewPic.requestLayout();

// 75% width of the screen taken by the image
mImageViewPic.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (getContext().getResources()
                                                .getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.75);

// height = 1.5 * width
mImageViewPic.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (mImageViewPic
                                                .getLayoutParams().width * 1.5);
```

**What I'm looking for is an efficient solution to these requirements through XML not programtically.
I know that you can set the width using layout weights as 75% but how do you set height after that?**

I hope my requirements are clear. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).
for example if you want 16:9 aspect ratio you should add something like this to your PercentRelativeLayout :

```
 android:layout_width="300dp"
 app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use override(w,h) method in Glide for resize